# Find the distance such that the angle will be the gratest

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

Rectangle shaped screen in a cinema is 8m high. It is place on a wall in such a manner that the upper edge of the screen is 12m above the floor. Find the distance between the viewer and the wall where the screen is placed, such that the angle from which the viewer can watch the screen will be the greatest (measured vertically, between lower and the upper edge of the screen). We assume that the viewer sits in the middle of the row and that eyes of the viewer are situated 1.5m above the ground.

Obviously that is the optimisation question, but i need to find the distance which will maximize the angle, however i have completely no idea how to find th expression i need to minimize. Thus what will be this expression? I hope i will manage to do the latter part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the viewer is sitting a distance $x$ from the screen, and her eyes are a distance $d_1=2.5$ m below the bottom of the screen and $d_2=10.5$ m below the top of the screen. There are two right triangles in this problem. The first has endpoints at the viewer's eyes, the bottom of the screen, and the wall below the screen, directly forward from the viewer's eyes. The second has endpoints at the viewer's eyes, the top of the screen, and the wall below the screen, directly in front of the viewer's eyes. These triangles have both have a leg (the horizontal one) of length $x$. They have vertical legs of lengths $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively. We can calculate the angle from the bottom of the screen: $\theta_1=\arctan(d_1/x)$ and the angle from the top of the screen: $\theta_2=\arctan(d_2/x)$. Finally, to get the angle the screen occupies, we subtract these: $\theta=\theta_2-\theta_1$. Now take a derivative with respect to $x$, and solve for the optimizing point.